# Spnego cross-domain configuration

Tags: tomcat, kerberos, spnego

I've sucessfully configured a Tomcat with integrated ([Spnego/Kerberos](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/index.html)) authentication on a single Active Directory domain, `DOMAINA`.

However, my company decided to split `DOMAINA` in two:

- `DOMAINA` with users
- `DOMAINB` with services and servers that deliver them

Domains are trusted.
Now i have to configure Tomcat (and Spnego), which is now running on `DOMAINB` to authenticate all `DOMAINA` users.

Some questions:

- the preauth user should be a `DOMAINA` or `DOMAINB` user?
- have i to ask for a new native `DOMAINB` preauth user or i can configure the username parameter as `DOMAINA\OLDPREAUTHUSER`?
- how the SPN's should be adjusted? with `DOMAINA\OLDPREAUTHUSER` or have i to define now for `DOMAINB\NEWPREAUTHUSER` (with omitted redundant `DOMAINB\` prefix)?
- i also changed `krb5.conf`:

  [libdefaults]

  ```
  default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
  default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
  permitted_enctypes   = rc4-hmac
  default_realm = DOMAINA
  ```

  [realms]

  ```
  DOMAINA = {
      kdc = KDCA
      default_domain = DOMAINA
  ```

  }

  ```
  DOMAINB = {
      kdc = KDCB
      default_domain = DOMAINB
  ```

  }

  [domain_realm]

  ```
  .DOMAINB = DOMAINB
  .DOMAINA = DOMAINA
  ```

Is it correct? What should be the default domain?

Sorry but the editor won't format code well...

Answer (score 0):

The default realm is where your machine is part of. I.e., the machine account is always bound to one and only one domain. Please note that `DOMAIN\USER` is pre-Windows 2000 style and deprecated. User in NTLM only. If you deal with Kerberos, you deal with UPNs and SPNs only.